# PHP prepared statement within a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm going through a video tutorial about doing a menu using a db. Instead of doing it with procedural PHP like in the video, I tried doing it with prepared statements OOP style. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

It runs fine until line 17, where it dies with this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\widget_corp\content.php on line 17`

And here's the code:

```
    <?php
        $query = $connection->prepare('SELECT menu_name, id FROM subjects ORDER BY position ASC;');
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($menu_name, $sid);

        while ($query->fetch()){
            echo "<li>{$menu_name} {$sid}</li>";

            $query2 = $connection->prepare('SELECT menu_name FROM pages WHERE subject_id = ? ORDER BY position ASC;');
            $query2->bind_param("i", $sid); //This is line 17
            $query2->execute();
            $query2->bind_result($menu_name);
            echo "<ul class='pages'>";              
            while ($query2->fetch()){
                echo "<li>{$menu_name}</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";

        }
        $query->close();
    ?>
```

Is it impossible to do a prepared statement within stmt->fetch();?

Comment: You're using the mysqli extension, right? Have you considered using PDO instead? With PDO you can have exceptions as "error handler" which makes it a bit harder for you to miss sql errors (like the one most probably caused by line 16 in this case ;-))

Comment: Yeah it's mysqli, but it's not an sql error. Ran the SQL query in a terminal, worked fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out:

After executing and binding the result, it has to be stored (if another prepared statement is to be put in the fetch). So the fetching in this case has to be read from a buffered result.

In other words, can't execute another query until a fetch on the same connection is in progress.

The working code:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT menu_name, id FROM subjects ORDER BY position ASC;");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($menu_name, $sid);
$query->store_result();
```

Comment: "...it has to be stored".. life saver!

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT menu_name, id FROM subjects ORDER BY position ASC");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $menu_name, $id);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
 $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($con2,"SELECT menu_name FROM pages WHERE subject_id = ? ORDER BY position ASC;");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,$id);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $name);
 while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2))
  echo $name;
}
```

look at the $con and $con2, you can not execute a prepare statement within another ps using the same connection !!!

Comment: in this case there is no need to store the result, so u u saving memory and time :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have several prepared statements : one of the ideas of prepared statements is "**prepare once, execute several times**".

- So, you should prepare the statement outside of the loop -- so it's prepared only once
- And execute it, several times, insidde the loop.

The Fatal error you get means that `$query2` on line 17, is not an object -- which means the `prepare` failed.

A `prepare` typically fails when there is an error in it ; are you sure your query is valid ? The tables and columns names are OK ?

You should be able to get an error message, when the `prepare` fails, using [`mysqli->error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) -- or [`PDO::errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: The query works fine if I take it out of the loop. And the "i" is for integer so that it knows to put an integer in place of the ?. It's not bound to a name.

Comment: Humph, sorry about that, I forgot how that worked :-( I've removed this portion of my answer... Did you try getting the error message caused by the preparation ?

Comment: If I take the inside prepare and put it outside I just doesn't do anything. No errors yet no result either. And I cant get any other error messages besides the original one for the prepare. (Btw, you have some insanely fast response time and a big thank you from me)

Comment: Humph, that's odd ; maybe someone else will have an idea... *(well, I'm not always on SO either -- but when I am, I sometimes answer :-) )*

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what DB extension you are using but you don't seem to test the return value of any function you are using. You can't assume that DB calls will always run flawlessly.